# Built-in alarm clock on G2?

Tags: htc-desire-z, alarm

I just upgraded from G1 to G2 Android. The G1 had a decent alarm clock application built right into it. The G2 doesn't seem to have this app (or I can't seem to find it.) Anyone know how to access it if there is one?

Comment: Are you referring to the "Clock" app?

Comment: No worries, I too had this problem switching from the G1, thought they made a huge oversight in removing the alarm clock...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think they changed the name of the stock Clock app during one of the Android OS upgrades.

In 2.1 I think it was called "Desk Clock".  In 2.2 it's just called "Clock".

Comment: Thanks! Found it about 5 minutes after I posted this lol. Woke me up this morning :)